# Converting a Object[] array to an int [] array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, integer

It appears there is no easy way of doing this, but this is what i've done so far and if someone could correct it to make it work that would be great. At "newarray [e] = array [i].intValue ();" i get an error "No method named "intValue" was found in type "java.lang.Object"."
Help!

```
/*
Description: A game that displays digits 0-9 and asks the user for a number N.
 It then reverses the first N numbers of the sequence. It continues this until
 all of the numbers are in order.
 numbers

*/

import hsa.Console;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class ReversalGame3test

{
    static Console c;

    public static void main (String[] args)
{
    c = new Console ();

    c.println ("3. REVERSAL GAME");
    c.println ("");
    c.println ("Displayed below are the digits 0-9 in random order. You must then enter a");
    c.println ("number N after which the computer will reverse the first N numbers in the");
    c.println ("sequence. The goal of this game is to sort all of the numbers in the fewest");
    c.println ("number of reversals.");
    c.println (""); //introduction

    List numbers = new ArrayList ();
    numbers.add ("0");
    numbers.add ("1");
    numbers.add ("2");
    numbers.add ("3");
    numbers.add ("4");
    numbers.add ("5");
    numbers.add ("6");
    numbers.add ("7");
    numbers.add ("8");
    numbers.add ("9");
    Collections.shuffle (numbers);
    Object[] array = numbers.toArray (new String [10]); // declares + shuffles numbers and converts them to array

    c.print ("Random Order: ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        c.print ((array [i]) + " ");
    }
    c.println ("");

    boolean check = false;
    boolean check2 = false;
    String NS;
    int N = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int e = -1;
    int[] newarray = new int [10];

    //INPUT
    do
    {
        c.print ("Enter a number: ");
        NS = c.readString ();
        count += 1;

        check = isInteger (NS);
        if (check == true)
        {
            N = Integer.parseInt (NS);
            if (N < 1 || N > 10)
            {
                check = false;
                c.println ("ERROR - INPUT NOT VALID");
                c.println ("");
            }
            else
            {
                c.print ("Next Order: ");
                for (int i = N - 1 ; i > -1 ; i--)
                {
                    e += 1;
                    newarray [e] = array [i].intValue ();
                    c.print ((newarray [e]) + " ");
                }
                for (int i = N ; i < 10 ; i++)
                {
                    e += 1;
                    newarray [e] = array [i].intValue ();
                    c.print ((newarray [e]) + " ");
                }
                check2 = sorted (newarray);
            } // rearranges numbers if valid
        } // checks if N is valid number
    }
    while (check == false);
} // main method


public static boolean isInteger (String input)
{
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt (input);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        return false;
    }
} //isInteger method


public static boolean sorted (int array[])
{
    boolean isSorted = false;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        if (array [i] < array [i + 1])
        {
            isSorted = true;
        }
        else if (array [i] > array [i + 1])
        {
            isSorted = true;
        }
        else
            isSorted = false;

        if (isSorted != true)
            return isSorted;
    }
    return isSorted;
} // sorted method
```

}

Comment: Why do you create an array of `Object` in the first place?

Comment: because i had no choice, it wouldn't let me convert the ArrayList to an int array directly.

Comment: You could use an array of `Integer`.

Comment: but I still cannot compare an Integer array like I would an int one, and if so I don't know how to

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Integer.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

```
Integer.valueOf((String) array [i])
```

The `Integer` class has a method `valueOf` which takes a string as the value and returns a `int` value, you can use this. It will throw an `NumberFormatException` if the string passed to it is not a valid integer value.

Also If you are using java5 or higher you can try using [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) to make the code more readable.

Comment: I'm questioning the efficiency of this solution (not as if it matters significantly in this case). Is there a benefit to casting `(String)` then using `Integer.valueOf()` over `(Integer)` then `intValue()` that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: The problem is `array` is not an `Interger[]` it is an `Object[]` containing `String` values so `(Integer)array[i]` should throw an class cast exception.

Comment: Just tested that, no exception thrown here. Statement `((Integer)x[1]).intValue()` returns the appropriate value where `x` is an array of type `Object[]` and `x[1]` is not null.

Comment: Can you check again because it just give me `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` error on line `newarray[e] = ((Integer)array[i]).intValue();`. If you see the code `array` contains `String` values, java will not allow you to cast a `String` value to a `Integer` value, again it is not a compile time error it is a runtime exception, so you need to execute the code to get the exception

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. I was operating under the assumption that the values were stored as type `int`, not type `String`, because storing as `String` would be generally silly for something like this. I see the error now.

Comment: All I get is an error message saying `you cannot assign a java.lang.Integer expression to an int variable`
Can I make newarray[] type Integer and then convert it to int? If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the same using [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), which would be easier.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
Integer[] array = numbers.toArray (new Integer [10]);
```

Comment: Anytime I try to use any code with "< >" I get 'invalid assignment operator'. Do you know why/how to fix?

Comment: Are you using java5 or higher version... Generics is supported only from java5...

Comment: I suppose not then, I'm using something called "Ready to Program" for java

Answer (score 3):

have a try 
commons-lang

```
org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(Integer[])
```

Comment: I have no idea how to go about doing whatever that means. Sorry, I have an awful comp.sci. teacher.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `.intValue()` on an `Object`, as the `Object` class lacks the method `intValue()`.

Instead, you need to cast the `Object` to the `Integer` class first, like so:

```
newarray[e] = ((Integer)array[i]).intValue();
```

Edit: Just a helpful tip on StackOverflow - please limit your code to what's relevant! Though sometimes large blocks of code are necessary, in this case, it was not. It makes the question look nicer, and it's bound to get better responses that way.

Also, please do not use the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag. It is currently deprecated and is in the process of burnination.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted the answers to be most accurate since I`ve searched on this site for hours for a solution and have found nothing.
I tried your suggestion and it said java.lang.ClassCastException at that line...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty late, but here are my 2 cents!!

```
int[] newArray=new int[objectArray.length];
Object[] objectArray = {1,2,3,4,5};

for(int i=0;i<objectArray.length();i++){
    b[i]=(int)objectArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that user needs to convert `Object[]` to `Integer[]`.

Simply use `Arrays.copyOf`. Full documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

```
Object [] temp = {1,2,3,4,5};
Integer[] result = Arrays.copyOf(temp, temp.length, Integer[].class);
```